# Multiple horizontal line separators? Multiple \over-s?

Tags: matrices, fractions

How to code the syntax like fraction, but with more than 2 components? Fractions consist of numerator and denominator while I need more. In other words: how to code column-matrix with horizontal lines separations (and without any surrounding brackets).

P.S. All components should be of equal size not like in

```
{a \over {b \over {c \over d}}}
```

Comment: You didn't say what format you are using, mostly LaTeX is assumed but you mentioned `\over` which isn't really a LaTeX command. Something like {\scriptstyle\begin{array}{c}1\\2\\3\\4\\5\\6\end{array}}` should work in LaTeX/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

$\begin{array}{c}a\\ \hline b\\ \hline c\\ \hline d\end{array}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively you can use the `matrix` environment from `amsmath` instead of the `array` environment.

Comment: This is not very clear and I don't understand why this got accepted as an answer. For example, is this a/(b/(c/d)), (a/b)/(c/d). (a/(b/c))/d,....?

Answer (score 3):

I think `array` solution is probably what you are looking for, but can also do this with nested fractions:

[image]

### Notes:

- The second `\dfrac` version has an issue with as the height/dept of the characters is not uniform.  Adding a `\mathstrut` fixes that (Thanks to **egreg**).

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[ 
  \frac{\frac{a}{b}}{\frac{c}{d}}  \quad \frac{\dfrac{a}{b\mathstrut}}{\dfrac{c\mathstrut}{d}}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Add `\mathstrut` next to the `c`: `\dfrac{\mathstrut c}{d}`. You may be wanting to do the same for `b`.

Comment: This is a much clearer solution.